# NullPointer on Firebase String Item

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I am testing Firebase on two items. I am hoping to update a recyclerview to add an item, with the firebase onChildAdded() listener prompting the recyclerview to update. Here is the code where I write to Firebase:

```
 mSubmitPollCreation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //TODO: Need to determine if this is proper epoch - i.e. does it account for time zones
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            final String epochTime = String.valueOf(c.getTimeInMillis());

            //TODO: Need to check if poll requirements are added, i.e. Question, Answer, ......
            //check if image has been loaded first
            if (resultImageURL != null){
                mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime).child("Image_URL").setValue(resultImageURL);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.no_image_selected),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            //Add Answer Counter defaulted to 0
            Map<String, Object> pollAnswerCounter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            pollAnswerCounter.put("Vote_Count", 0);
            mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime).updateChildren(pollAnswerCounter);

            //Add Question
            Map<String, Object> pollQuestion = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            pollQuestion.put("Question", mCreatePollQuestion.getText().toString());
            mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime).updateChildren(pollQuestion);

            if (mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser > 5){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getText(R.string.poll_answers_greater_than_five),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser = 5;
            }
            //add answers to Firebase
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser; i++){
                EditText editText = (EditText) mEditTextAnswerLayout.findViewWithTag(getResources().getString(R.string.created_answer_editText_id)+String.valueOf(i+1));
                String editTextInputForAnswer = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
                final String answerLabel = "Answer";
                Map<String, Object> answerChoice = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                answerChoice.put(answerLabel, editTextInputForAnswer);
                mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime).child("Answers").child(String.valueOf(i+1)).updateChildren(pollAnswerCounter);
                mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime).child("Answers").child(String.valueOf(i+1)).updateChildren(answerChoice);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),editTextInputForAnswer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Intent toHomeActivity = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            toHomeActivity.putExtra("viewpager_position", 2);
            startActivity(toHomeActivity);
        }
    });
```

Here is the code, in a separate fragment, that I use to retrieve the data from Firebase:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String newPollEpoch = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.v("Child_Added", "The new child is " + newPollEpoch);
            String newPollImageURL = dataSnapshot.child(IMAGE_URL).getValue().toString();
            String newPollQuestion = dataSnapshot.child(QUESTION_STRING).getValue().toString();
            mNewPollsAray.add(0, new Poll(newPollQuestion, newPollImageURL, newPollEpoch));
            mNewPollsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mPollsRef.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPollsRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
}
```

And here is the error. It is quite odd, as the error is prompting on the "String newPollQuestion." I use the exact same method to write the "newPollImageURL" to Firebase, and that object is not null. Also, there are 2 devices, A and B. A creates and writes the item to Firebase, and then reads it fine. B is the device that is displaying the following:

```
12-03 16:21:20.255 21043-21043/com.troychuinard.fanpolls E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.troychuinard.fanpolls, PID: 21043
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.Fragment.NewFragment$1.onChildAdded(NewFragment.java:159)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaip.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


                                                                       --------- beginning of system
```

Comment: Can you do a JSON export of the data that got into the database?

Comment: How do you do that? It is weird, because on the second device if I am actively on the screen/activity where firebase is updated, there is an error. But if I am on a different screen/activity and then navigate to that screen/activity, everything loads fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why, but changing:

```
String newPollQuestion = dataSnapshot.child(QUESTION_STRING).getValue.toString;
```

to:

```
String newPollQuestion = dataSnapshot.child(QUESTION_STRING).getValue(String.class);
```

Successfully removed the NullPointer. Any idea why?

Comment: getValue() on DataSnapshot can return null if there is no data at the requested path.  You took that null and then tried to call toString() on it.  The javadoc is unfortunately not clear that getValue() can return null.

Comment: Then how did it work when I changed it to String.class if it was null?

Comment: Did it work?  I suspect that getValue(String.class) was also returning null, and you put that into your Poll object, which probably ended up in a TextView after that.  Putting a null into a TextView is OK.

Comment: Right, so you passed along a null value as I suspected?

Comment: I don't believe it is null as I have a value in Fieebase that I store to that string